# Boost asio - можно ли переиспользовать сокет?

Tags: c++, asio, boost.asio

После того, как я:

- создал сокет
- поставил его ан прослушивание
- получил Входящее "сообщение" от Клиента
- "обработал" Входящее сообщнице и закрыл сокет...

То можно ли этот сокет опять поставить на прослушивание ?
Эксперимент показывает, что нет - функция accept() - выдает ошибку.

Можно ли, как то закрытый сокет условно "сбросить" в первончальное состояние ? Чтобы не освобождать ранее выделенную память под этот сокет и чтобы не создавать новый сокет, который в итоге тоже придется удалить.

PS: в данном случае имеются ввиду tcp-сокеты.

Comment: Что-то у вас какая-то каша в вопросе. В TCP-сокетах нет сообщений, есть создание соединения, и accept создаёт второй сокет, и при закрытии сокета нужно уточнять, какой конкретно сокет вы закрываете. В UDP-сокетах наоборот есть только сообщения, никаких соединений нет и никакого accept тоже нет и закрывать ничего не надо. Уточните вопрос, какие конкретно сокеты вы используете, и желательно приведите пример проблемного кода

Comment: @andreymal, tcp-сокеты. Под "сообщением" я имел ввиду просто переданные байты. Что значит accept создаёт второй сокет ? Может я не вызываю accept до тех пор, пока не закрою первый созданный сокет и после чего подсовывают accept этот "закрытый" сокет.

Comment: *"Эксперимент показывает, что нет - функция accept() - выдает ошибку."* - эксперименты и ошибку в студию